# Need help in grouping the columns together for Year and Months

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting different sum for total "**Customers**" in "Year wise" i.e. first query and "Month wise" i.e. second query.

```
select year(order_date), year(first_order_date),
count(distinct customer_mobile) as 'Customers',
count(customer_mobile) as 'Orders',
sum(order_amount)
from order_table
group by year(order_date),year(first_order_date)
```

vs

```
select year(order_date), month(order_date), year(first_order_date),
count(distinct customer_mobile) as 'Customers',
count(customer_mobile) as 'Orders',
sum(order_amount)
from order_table
group by year(order_date),month(order_date),year(first_order_date)
```

Thanks

[image: Output Required like this image and so on...]

Comment: I don't really now how you data looks like but my guess is that in the second query the grouping is "finer". That is if there were orders in more than 1 months they will be in different groups and therefore you will get different results.

Answer (score 0):

Different sum because in first query you have grouped by two years

so the sum will be by years .

in the second query you added group by month which all results will be by month, its not same by year and by month .

example

```
    user1 ---> 40 per year /if you group by year
```

and

```
   user1---> 10 january , 10 favruary , 5 mars ,... ///---if you group by month.
```

Comment: Can you please help me out in writing the proper query then? - Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand anything. better give sample data and your wished result.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, the customer is counted just once if he has several orders in a single year. In the second query the customer is counted once for each year/month combination.

You can try this for your second query:

```
select CONCAT(year(order_date), '-', month(order_date)) as yearmonth,
year(first_order_date),
count(distinct customer_mobile) as 'Customers',
count(customer_mobile) as 'Orders',
sum(order_amount)
from order_table
group by CONCAT(year(order_date), '-', month(order_date)),year(first_order_date)
```

Comment: Its the Same result as before... :(